# How to set value in c++ unordered_map and return reference?

Tags: c++, hashmap

So this is silly:

```cpp
Nodes[pos] = node;
return &Nodes[pos];
```

because I insert and then do a lookup. I tried like this:

```cpp
return &Nodes.emplace(pos, node).first->second;
```

but it doesn't return the reference.

Comment: The `&` symbol in this context is the address-of operator. It would be useful if you wanted to return a pointer, not a reference. Assuming the return type of your function is a reference, you could just do `return Nodes.emplace(pos, node).first->second;`

Comment: @NathanPierson sorry for not clarifying it. I want a ref. pointer. But it seems doesn't work.

Comment: What is "ref. pointer"?

Comment: `return Nodes[pos] = node;` will work just fine as long as the assignment operator of the value type is conventional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `insert`/`emplace` like this:

```cpp
int& f1(std::unordered_map<int, int>& m) {
  auto [iterator, was_inserted] = m.insert({10, 100});
  return iterator->second;
}
```

`operator[]` can also create the key if it doesn't exist, so you can also do:

```cpp
int& f2(std::unordered_map<int, int>& m) {
  auto& node = m[10];
  node = 100;
  return node;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I should. Thanks :)